# Established methods for websites to serve database results

Tags: javascript, sql, database, rest

Are there established methods or frameworks for serving database rows to web clients?  So far I just have them submit a JSON object ex

```
{
  Query: "SELECT",
  Schema: "icecream",
  Table: "cones",
  Fields: ["price", "flavor"],
  Filters: [
    {
      "Comparison": "=",
      "Field": "flavor",
      "Value": "chocolate"
    }
  ]
}
```

I verify that the fields mentioned are authorized/correct, then construct a prepared statement mysql string, but are there any frameworks, or standard methods of implementing this?

Comment: php via ajax???

Answer (score 0):

Truth be told, what you are doing is very unusual.  You are effectively giving your web client full access to build queries for your database.  You mention that you are validating the information before building the query, which is good, because the risk of SQL injection is very high.  You are asking a very broad question, so I will respond with an equally broad answer:

No, there are no frameworks or standards to implementing this.  The reason is because (unless you have a very specific reason for doing this), very few web applications are setup to give the web client such extensive control over the queries being built.  Normally your backend APIs would intentionally be much more limited.  You are effectively implementing an API method that says:

1. Give me the details of your query and I will build and execute it for you and return the result.

Normally standard operating procedure otherwise is to have much more specific and limited API methods.  Rather than having a generic query builder you would have an API for each specific thing that has to happen:

1. Tell me how many records you want and a search value on this small handful of fields and I will return a list of matching users
2. Tell me how many records you want and which of these fields you want to sort by and I will return a list of matching books

That is not to say that there aren't perfectly valid reasons to do it the way you are trying to do it, but unless there is a reason why you specifically want to give users full control over the query building process, I think the first step is to refactor in a way that gives the web client less control, and your server-side application more.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you're reinventing a query language!

Why not allow your users to type SQL queries directly? Or mongodb queries, or whatever DBMS you use. There is much less overhead.

When it comes to security, a good practice is to setup a clone of your database (a *read-only replica*), and have your clients hit the read-only replica instead of the main database node.

Your main node and your read-only replica can stay in sync using replication. Any good DBMS supports it.

A good example of this is the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/)